# Python SQLAlchemy - Constructing Case outside of session while using the mapped schema from the session

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having trouble building a Case statement outside of my query which i want to append to my query conditionally. The issue is that it's a multi-tenant database so the schema of the table must be mapped dynamically which is done when creating the session. For example table_user_1 vs table_user_2. The base class has `__table_args__ = {"schema": "table_user"}` so when I construct my case statement like this

```
data = case(
        [
            (
                table.data == "data",
                table.data,
            ),
            (
                other_table.data == "data",
                other_table.data
            ),
        ],
    )
```

it is using the schema defined in the class as "table_user" instead of the needed dynamically set schema in my session which would be table_user_1.

I've tried to setup a class constructor that inherits from this table and sets the table_args but run into some errors about it already being defined by the base table.

```
@staticmethod
    def setup_schema(user_id: str):
        return type("DynamicUserTable", (table,), {
            "__table_args__": {schema": f"table_user_{user_id}"}
        })
```

For context of why i'm doing this... I am trying to make a 1 stop shop to add filters to my query where I can pass parameters to my function and it will append filters to the query. Example:

```
    if argument_1:
        query = query.filter(table_1.data == argument_1)
```

I'm using the case statement to build a new column and then compare that column to the argument. The problem being that it's using the table definitions **table_args** attribute which should be set dynamically so it fails because the table doesn't exist under the schema it's looking.

Would be nice to reference my session for the case statement but i'm not seeing how I could do that.

I tried to add an inheritance class constructor that dynamically creates new classes with the correct schema.

Answer (score 0):

Aha... I can actualy define the case statement inside the query using

```
query.filter(
            case(
                [
                    (
                        table_2.data == data,
                        table_2.data
                    )
                ],
                else_=table.data
            )
        )
```